# Can't delete photo via Facebook API?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Suddenly, I can't delete Facebook photos via the API. I get this error:

```
Array ( [error] => Array ( [type] => OAuthException [message] => (#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call. ) )
```

What does this mean? It suddenly stopped working. Is Facebook blocking this? I have read that. Is there a work-around?

Comment: It seems to me there isn't a solution yet. Keep tracking facebook forums.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that link. It really sucks how Facebook changed their API without telling their developers. Why would they do that? Ehhh, it just stinks. Guess people can't delete their photos via my app. It's all good.

Comment: As i understand it, deleting wasn't supposed to be available, and was accidentally working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct; there is currently no public access to delete photos from an album via the Facebook API.

This is intentional and there are no known workarounds. An App can delete open graph actions or Feed stories that it has made, but not most other types of content, including photos.

Comment: Is there any rollback expected to this in future? If a properly scoped and authorized access token is being sent, whats the harm in allowing deletion?

Comment: I think it would be handy if an app that created a photo was also allowed to delete it. I can see not allowing apps to just arbitrarily delete any photo/post of the user's.

Comment: Actually apps can delete photos they created by simply calling a delete method on the resource ID. Using a curl/file_get_contents on https://graph.facebook.com/ID?method=DELETE&access_token=TOKEN where ID is the photo id and TOKEN the access token for the user-application pair.

Comment: @mariomc if thats the case, you probably should create an answer stating that.  Assuming you're correct, people will come here and if they don't read as far as your comment will get mis-information

Answer (score 1):

As of December 2012, apps can only delete photos **they created**.

This deletion is done by simply calling a delete method on the resource ID. Using, for instance, a curl/file_get_contents on http://graph.facebook.com/[ID]?method=DELETE&access_token=[TOKEN] where [ID] is the photo id and [TOKEN] the access token for the user-application pair.

Answer (score 0):

I paste this comment here to someone easy to find

"Actually apps can delete photos they created by simply calling a delete method on the resource ID. Using a curl/file_get_contents on https://graph.facebook.com/ID?method=DELETE&access_token=TOKEN where ID is the photo id and TOKEN the access token for the user-application pair. –  mariomc Dec 17 '12 at 17:07"

I tested, it worked like a charm, thank you

```
$delete = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/<id photo>?method=DELETE&access_token=<access_token>');
echo $delete;
die;
```

you can find access_token at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/, copy token can access to photo or page's photo.