# How to remove uploaded photo from facebook wall from application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I have a specific requirement that requires to remove the uploaded photo from facebook wall .The photo will be uploaded from the application too .We have post ids stored in database for each uploaded image.

Problem : i am unable to delete the uploaded photo by post id .I am able to delete the posted status by same way but when i try to delete the posted image than it gives me false response .

I am using facebook sdk version 3.0 .
Which uses graph api to get each object.

You can refer this link
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

What i have found is , when you perform the same DELETE operation as per this link it will simply do unlike operation on the photo but couldnt remove it from the wall.

This is the link to graph api explorer tool of facebook 
[link](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

For example :
This is my post id : 100004659372340_187089248123053

But when i try to search my uploaded image via graph api explorer using this post id it gives me this error

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

I have given all permission from my facebook account.
Why i am not able to search my uploaded photo from graph explorer ?

Please help me out with this.

I thank you in advance for paying attention to this .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't delete photo via Facebook API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337969/cant-delete-photo-via-facebook-api)

Comment: Difference is that , facebook is now providing graphApi which is accessible  for everyone and they can say that we can access any data using their graph api explorer , so my question was particularly targeting that , and my problem is i am uploading the photo from my application , so i can delete it via post id.But it gives me false response.

Comment: I am also using sdk 3.0 ,so there are chances that they have given permission to delete the photo in newer versions of their sdks .

Comment: Isn't [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6747899/1515819) saying that an app can't delete its own photos or am I missing something?

Comment: No, you are correct from your side , i just want to know that facebook has done some recent changes in their sdks and graph API.And they are claiming to access anything by post id.So why we cant delete the same photo content by post.Even i am able to delete the status update.

Comment: I select Delete request from graph api and delete the photo and its deleted easily. No problem there

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to delete photos created by your app.  If you're encountering issues please log a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create and post the link here so others can subscribe.

Comment: sure,thanks for the link i am going to post the bug report.:)