# how to delete photo post id facebook by grab api php with curl

Tags: php, facebook, curl

i try to delete photos i have uploaded with app by php

the result of upload example :

```
 {"id":"429774393794352","post_id":"276744849097308_429774413794350"}
```

first which one id or post_id   will be use

and how to select it with php ??

and how to make order to delete it with php code by curl library

my idea is ,  i will store all photos ids into sql to delete it any time

my upload code i used

```
$file='./'.$new_string;






$args = array(
   'message' => $message,
);
$args[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($file);
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/album id /photos?access_token='.$accsesss;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
$a1=$data = curl_exec($ch);
print_r(json_decode($data,true));
echo'<br/>';
```

i try

```
$args = array(
   'id' => '276744849097308_429774413794350',
   'access_token' => $accsesss ,


);
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/276744849097308_429774413794350?method=DELETE&access_token=$accsesss';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); $a1=$data = curl_exec($ch);
print_r(json_decode($data,true));
echo'<br/>';
```

result

```
Array ( [error] => Array ( [message] => Invalid OAuth access token. [type] => OAuthException [code] => 190 ) )
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos

Comment: what url of  HTTP DELETE   and how to select it with php?

Comment: POST request to https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/photos?method=delete.  that will work ??

Comment: You will have to specify the photo id as well somehow – but the docs seem to say nothing about how to actually do that – hm … I’d try just issuing a DELETE request to `/photoid`, as deleting in general should work according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/deleting/

Comment: Yes, according to this answer that should work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15922929/1427878

Comment: $args = array(
   'id' => '276744849097308_429774413794350',
   'access_token' => $accsesss ,


);
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/276744849097308_429774413794350?method=DELETE&access_token=$accsesss';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); $a1=$data = curl_exec($ch);
print_r(json_decode($data,true));
echo'<br/>';   give me  Array ( [error] => Array ( [message] => Invalid OAuth access token. [type] => OAuthException [code] => 190 ) )

Comment: I think you missed `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);` in the "DELETE" cURL call

Answer (score 1):

```
 $Curl_Session = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/429774393794352');
 curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "method=DELETE&access_token=$masteracsess");
 curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

 echo $a8=curl_exec ($Curl_Session);
 curl_close ($Curl_Session);
```

thanks for your help @CBroe